# Netbeans 7.3 highlights error for xhtml when custom attributes are used in JSF components

Tags: jsf-2, netbeans-7, highlighting

We are running an existing project in JSF. And we have added some attributes to components which are not part of the tag library. For example we have added `placeholder` attribute to `h:inputText` component. Now when we use that attribute on a xhtml page, NetBeans 7.3 highlights the page as erroneous in the IDE which can confuse us during development as we might skip a real error in the page assuming that the editor highlights this strange case.

This was not happening while we were working with version 7.2, is there a way for defining this custom attribute to NetBeans 7.3 so that it doesn't highlight this error when we use custom attributes.

Somebody else already asked this question on the NetBeans forum but still didn't get any answer:
http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic54141.html

Hope SO might help
Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. What is your workaround? To use Netbeans 7.2 ?

Comment: Couldn't find any solution yet waiting for a batch or smtg. I ignore those errors for now =(

Comment: Has there been any progress in this issue? It still occurs with Netbeans 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
 <h:form>
<h:inputText p:type="password" p:class="input-lg form-control" p:name="password1" p:placeholder="Password" />
</h:form>
```

Try using this way to solve.

Comment: That is not a solution. the passthrough library just scapes HTML 5 attributes but does not process them as expected with JSF attributes like omnifaces converter list for instance: